# html(jQuery): element.outerWidth() doesn't return the correct pixel width

Tags: jquery, html

I need the precise width of a header of a table so that I can calculate how much room there is left. I tried calling $("element id").outerWidth() but it returns too small a pixel width. When I use inspect element on a header in firefox, the width display in the little popup above the selected element shows a correct width. But the pixel width displayed in the box model tab is the same as the one returned by .outerWidth(). All the margins and paddings are zero.

What does this mean, and is there a way to get the width displayed in the popup?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle reproducing this issue?